# BizTalk can not deploy

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a BizTalk 2010 installed properly on window server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 on a different server. When I create a project myself, I can deploy it to the BizTalk server fine. But when I deploy a sample project from someone else, I got this error at deployment: "Parameter name: strDBName"

When I look at my deployment tab on the property of my project, the configuration database was disabled. I am sure the connection is fine and I can get to it with the project I created. Just not the project from someone else.
[image]

It seems unreasonable to ask for sysadmin privilege and my DBA will surely not allow. Is there something I can do to deploy project not created by myself other than asking for sysadmin privilege?

Answer (score 1):

You talk about disabling your config database on biztalk console, but the image provided is not biztak console. projects you open from someone will normally diable your configuration database area on biztalk project property page if the sample use a server other than yours.

Comment: You are right, my apologies. Good catch but my question is still the same. Is it possible to deploy BizTalk project not created by ourselves? If so, how do you do it? You may have tried to download samples and tutorials in the past, how do you run them? I hope you did not have to recreate everything from scratch?

Comment: yes I did. you open your project in VS and change the server and database in projet properties before deploying. you can provide the download url of your sample , and i'll try to deploye it on my  local server.

Comment: Thanks Hichamveo. My problem is when I changed to my server from the project property, the database was disabled as the picture above has shown. So, did you say you are able to deploy the BizTalk project without having to recreate it from scratch?

Comment: yes I can deploy downoaded project without having to create from scratch

Comment: Wow... I am interested to know how you can deploy without creating the project from scratch and without sysadmin privilege. Please clarify what do you mean by BizTalk management database well configured. We have a DBA who handles the database and it is up to date with patches and updates. My BizTalk system has been working for years without incident. I can not have sysadmin right on the database though because our DBA would not allow it and I also believe that asking for sysadmin to just be able to deploy a project may be too much to ask for.

Comment: the best way is to give me the utl to your sample, i'll downlad it and trying to deploy on my server to verify...